# Как осуществить подстановку необходимого значения в методе, при помощи ввода с клавиатуры HTML?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Здравствуйте, есть веб-интерфейс с различным функционалом, он подключён к СУБД Tarantool в котором реализована возможность поиска определённых кортежей по значению. Необходимо что бы эти значения вводились с веб-морды, и далее запускался нужный метод, к сожалению сам пока не могу это реализовать это. Значение которое нужно вводить с клавиатуры, `Arrays.asList(1491573042)`.

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    //socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("173.20.41.22", 3311));
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("173.20.25.75", 3311));
    Connection con = new Connection("admin", "admin", socket);

    //out.println("box.info:> " + con.call("box.info") + "\n");

    out.println("con.select :> " + con.select(512, 0, 
        Arrays.asList(1491573042), 0, 1024, 0) + "\n\n");

    con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error TarantoolConnection: " + e);
}
```

Comment: используйте JS для динамического изменения внешнего вида страницы и отправки запросов на сервер, которые будут вызывать необходимые функции, возвращая необходимые данные

Comment: Ваш вопрос выглядит как "Есть спецтехника с различным функционалом. Необходимо сделать в кабине рычаг, чтобы запускать механизм. Вот так выглядит одна из шестерёнок." Проще говоря, почти ничего не понятно. Конкретизируйте его, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если есть веб интерфейс, то покажи страницу с запросом. И код контроллера на который этот запрос мапится.

Comment: Ок, немного переформулирую, каким способом при помощи связки HTML/Servlet мне можно осуществить ручной ввод значения из веб-интерфейса в поле Arrays.asList(1491573042)?

Comment: В html-документ добавить форму, которая будет отправлять данные сервлету, который будет передавать полученные данные в метод `Arrays.asList()`.